# Rsync Output explanation

Tags: rsync

We have a script that "rsync" data to a remote server.That scriptt is working fine.Script that i am using is

```
date >> /home/abc/rsyncLogs/FS1.txt
rsync -zavru /FS1/ --delete --exclude-from '/home/abc/exclude-FS1.txt' username@RemoteSrvr:/FS1/. >> /home/abc/rsyncLogs/FS1.txt
date >> /home/abc/rsyncLogs/FS1.txt
```

I received output as

```
# tail FS1.txt

/.............
some files
................../

sent 3061704831 bytes  received 7340254 bytes  195374.80 bytes/sec
total size is 1218234805214  speedup is 396.94
<Date>
```

Please explain  what is sent bytes ,what is received bytes,what is total size,what is my network speed .

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much self-explanatory.

- Sent: `rsync` sent out X bytes for the various jobs that it does (comparing files and actually sending changed/new ones)
- Received: The same, other direction
- Total size: Without `rsync`, you would have to transmit X bytes
- speedup: The ratio between the total size and what has actually been transferred.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!!! . Please also let me know if X bytes are send,then why not full X bytes received,but a small part of X i.e Y is received .Is it because that rsync compares that out of X bytes only Y bytes are needed at destination..............is that so??

Comment: Please read the `rsync` man page to learn how it works. Only transmitting new/missing files or file-parts is what `rsync` is all about...

Answer (score 2):

Two `rsync` processes pass to each other an information about file hierarcies on the source and destination sides - pathes, sizes, CRCs, a/m/ctimes, ownership, permissions, flags and so on. Therefore source side not only sending but also receiving a lot of information to determine which files actually should be synced.

`Speedup` value is the ratio between the full size of source hierarcy and actually sended to the destination as newer/changed till the previous synchronization.